# c++ invalid pointer/double free on class with array member

Tags: c++, arrays, class, double, free

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int ALPHABET = 26;
const int LANG = 4;

const double TOLK[LANG][ALPHABET]= {{0}};

class Text
{
private:
  string sample;
  int* histogram;
  double* rel_histogram;
  int sample_size;

public:
  Text();
  ~Text();
  string parse();
};

string parsing(const double TOLK[][ALPHABET], double rel_occurence_arr[]);

int main()
{
  Text myText;
  myText.parse();

  return 0;
}

Text::Text(){
  sample = "";
  histogram = new int[ALPHABET];
  rel_histogram = new double[ALPHABET];
  sample_size = 0;
}

Text::~Text(){
  delete[] histogram;
  delete[] rel_histogram;
}

string Text::parse(){
  parsing(TOLK, rel_histogram);
  //Invalid pointer here
}

string parsing(const double TOLK_HJALP[][ALPHABET], double rel_occurence_arr[]){
  return "test";
}
```

This is part of a larger code, but I've peeled of everything I could till only the parts causing the error remains. Running it like this results in a invalid pointer error, running it with all the extra bits causes a double free/corruption error. But I think that if I can figure it out at this level I can probably figure it out at the larger scale.

From what I've gathered, I think that the Text class is trying to delete something which has already been deleted when the parsing function returned. I don't know if that is correct, but if it was, I have no idea on how to stop it from happening. It doesn't matter if I send a copy(in the way I tried, maybe there are more ways than one?).

And also, removing iostream from the include seems to remove the error, for whatever reason. Why is that? It isn't even used here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Text::parse() must return a value; otherwise it's UB. Also, you must #include <string>, since <iostream> is not guaranteed to do that for you. Other than that, the code you posted builds and runs with no errors in VS2017.

Comment: I feel incredibly stupid right now. That was it! Thanks for your help. Why don't the compiler give you a warning for that? It would seem fairly easy to detect for it.

Also, I think I know what UB means, but what does it stand for?

Comment: use -Wall and you will be enlighten.

Comment: UB: Undefined Behavior

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code that I can see.

(1) This should be what is causing your error. You are not including `string`, and `iostream` doesn't need to include it. This means you are returning a pointer to a char from `parsing`, but the pointer is deleted when `parsing` returns. This results in undefined behavior.

(2) `parse` doesn't return a value, but it promises to in its declaration. That could cause some issues.

Note: You should try using `-Wall` when you run into a problem (or just all the time). That would have caught both of those errors for you.